# Python: write fitparameters into table

Tags: python

I have some spectra in a folder and a Lorentzian peak should be fitted to the resonance curves. This works pretty well but I need to write the filenames fitparameters and the standart deviations of the fit into a .txt file.

At the moment it looks like this when is save the fitparameters:

Parameter[0],

Parameter[1],

Parameter[2],
....

but they should apper in the textfile like this:
Filename,Parameter[0],Parameter[1],Parameter[2],....

The code with which I save the parameters is shown here:

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('path/to/folder/', parameters, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Can we have the code where you write the parameters to the file?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your problem is that you don't know how to write variables into files without line seperation?

Comment: No. For every fiting procedure I get a filename and 8 fitting parameters. I want the results of one fit in a table side by side. The result of the next fit should be placed in the same table in a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution which is not very pretty....

At first I define an array with my "horizontal" dimensions

```
table=np.ndarray((9),int) #9 columns in my case
```

Then I have a loop which reads the file name as first column in the table and which writes everything into one line:

```
temp=[[name, fitparameter[0],...,fitparameter[n],std_devs[0],....,[std_devs[n]]
```

In the last step I just stack the new line to my initialized array

```
table=np.vstack([table,temp])
```

The ugly thing is, that the initialized array is not empty, so that I have to skip the first line of my table in the further code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, something like this should be what you want? If you're using numpy arrays, just convert them to a multidim list (like below) before using this and you should be good to go.

```
filename = "name" # logfile
fittings = [range(8) for fit in range(5)] # example data matrix

with open(filename,'w') as f:    
    for fit in fittings:
        fit.insert(0,"filexy") # the filename at the beginning of the line
        f.write(str(fit)[1:-1]+"\n") # write list, ignore brackets
```

produces file "name" with the content:

```
'filexy', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
'filexy', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
'filexy', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
'filexy', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
'filexy', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```